# PHP replacing special characters like à->a, è->e

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace, decode

I have php document signup.php which save the content from form (in form.php document) to MySQL base. The problem arises when I want to reformat the input content. I want do decode UTF-8 charachters like  à->a.

```
  $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
  $course=$_POST['course'];

  $chain="prêt-à-porter";

$pattern = array("'é'", "'è'", "'ë'", "'ê'", "'É'", "'È'", "'Ë'", "'Ê'", "'á'", "'à'", "'ä'", "'â'", "'å'", "'Á'", "'À'", "'Ä'", "'Â'", "'Å'", "'ó'", "'ò'", "'ö'", "'ô'", "'Ó'", "'Ò'", "'Ö'", "'Ô'", "'í'", "'ì'", "'ï'", "'î'", "'Í'", "'Ì'", "'Ï'", "'Î'", "'ú'", "'ù'", "'ü'", "'û'", "'Ú'", "'Ù'", "'Ü'", "'Û'", "'ý'", "'ÿ'", "'Ý'", "'ø'", "'Ø'", "'œ'", "'Œ'", "'Æ'", "'ç'", "'Ç'");

$replace = array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'y', 'y', 'Y', 'o', 'O', 'a', 'A', 'A', 'c', 'C'); 

$chain = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $chain);

echo $chain; // print pret-a-porter

$first_name =  preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $first_name);

echo $first_name; // does not change the input!?!
```

Why it works perfectly for $chain, but for $first_name or $last_name doesnt work?

Also i try

```
echo $first_name; // print áááááábéééééébšššš
$trans = array("á" => "a", "é" => "e", "š" => "s");
echo strtr("áááááábéééééébšššš", $trans); // print aaaaaabeeeeeebssss
echo strtr($first_name,$trans);  // print áááááábéééééébšššš
```

but the problem, as you can see, is same!

Comment: Does your file have the correct encoding? Does the stuff in $_POST have the same encoding? (i.e. the one you set for the browser to display the page with?) You may also want to set the unicode flag for preg_replace

Comment: As phant0m mentions, you need to keep close watch on all your encodings. Default encoding with POST is ISO-8859-1 unless you tell it specifically which you want. (accept-charset='UTF-8')

Comment: added a couple of example functions :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, when I add accept-charset="UTF-8" at the <form action="sign_up.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"> code working perfectly.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do this, using `iconv` - from the user notes, this seems to be what you want to do: [characters transliteration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#94946)

```
// PHP.net User notes
<?php
    $string = "ʿABBĀSĀBĀD";

    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $string);
    // output: [nothing, and you get a notice]

    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $string);
    // output: ABBSBD

    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
    // output: ABBASABAD
    // Yay! That's what I wanted!
?>
```

Be **very conscientious** with your character encodings, so you are keeping the same encoding at all stages in the process - front end, form submission, encoding of the source files. Default encoding in PHP and in forms is ISO-8859-1, before PHP 5.4 where it changed to be UTF8 (finally!).

There's a couple of functions you can play around with for ideas. First is from CakePHP's inflector class, called `slug`:

```
public static function slug($string, $replacement = '_') {
    $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($replacement, '/');

    $merge = array(
        '/[^\s\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
        '/\\s+/' => $replacement,
        sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
    );

    $map = self::$_transliteration + $merge;
    return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
}
```

It depends on a `self::$_transliteration` array which is similar to what you were doing in your question - you can [see the source for inflector on github](https://github.com/cakephp/utility/blob/master/Inflector.php).

Another is a function I use personally, which [comes from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150304084816/http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php).

```
function slugify($text,$strict = false) {
    $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    // replace non letter or digits by -
    $text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);

    // trim
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_GB.utf8');
    // transliterate
    if (function_exists('iconv')) {
        $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    }

    // lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // remove unwanted characters
    $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '', $text);
    if (empty($text)) {
        return 'empty_$';
    }
    if ($strict) {
        $text = str_replace(".", "_", $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

What those functions do is transliterate and create '[slugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29)' from arbitrary text input, which is a very very useful thing to have in your toolchest when making web apps.

Comment: Thank you for answer, the problem was that I have not added " accept-charset="UTF-8" " in the form.

Comment: welcome, i guess all those functions weren't really needed :) but may as well take a look.

Comment: I continued to use my function, because with it I can determine exactly with which letter I will replace some letter.

Comment: Is there anyway keeping åäö?

Comment: @embe use iso-8859-1 instead of ascii maybe?

Comment: Because the first pattern in `$merge` does not contain any anchors (`^`, `$`), the `m` pattern modifier is pointless.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a way to have some flexibility in what should be discarded and what should be replaced.
This is how I currently do it.

> $string = 'À some string with junk Ĩ Ä ';

```
$replace = [
    '&lt;' => '', '&gt;' => '', '&#039;' => '', '&amp;' => '',
    '&quot;' => '', 'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'Ae',
    '&Auml;' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A', 'Ā' => 'A', 'Ą' => 'A', 'Ă' => 'A', 'Æ' => 'Ae',
    'Ç' => 'C', 'Ć' => 'C', 'Č' => 'C', 'Ĉ' => 'C', 'Ċ' => 'C', 'Ď' => 'D', 'Đ' => 'D',
    'Ð' => 'D', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E', 'Ē' => 'E',
    'Ę' => 'E', 'Ě' => 'E', 'Ĕ' => 'E', 'Ė' => 'E', 'Ĝ' => 'G', 'Ğ' => 'G',
    'Ġ' => 'G', 'Ģ' => 'G', 'Ĥ' => 'H', 'Ħ' => 'H', 'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I',
    'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ī' => 'I', 'Ĩ' => 'I', 'Ĭ' => 'I', 'Į' => 'I',
    'İ' => 'I', 'Ĳ' => 'IJ', 'Ĵ' => 'J', 'Ķ' => 'K', 'Ł' => 'L', 'Ľ' => 'L',
    'Ĺ' => 'L', 'Ļ' => 'L', 'Ŀ' => 'L', 'Ñ' => 'N', 'Ń' => 'N', 'Ň' => 'N',
    'Ņ' => 'N', 'Ŋ' => 'N', 'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O',
    'Ö' => 'Oe', '&Ouml;' => 'Oe', 'Ø' => 'O', 'Ō' => 'O', 'Ő' => 'O', 'Ŏ' => 'O',
    'Œ' => 'OE', 'Ŕ' => 'R', 'Ř' => 'R', 'Ŗ' => 'R', 'Ś' => 'S', 'Š' => 'S',
    'Ş' => 'S', 'Ŝ' => 'S', 'Ș' => 'S', 'Ť' => 'T', 'Ţ' => 'T', 'Ŧ' => 'T',
    'Ț' => 'T', 'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'Ue', 'Ū' => 'U',
    '&Uuml;' => 'Ue', 'Ů' => 'U', 'Ű' => 'U', 'Ŭ' => 'U', 'Ũ' => 'U', 'Ų' => 'U',
    'Ŵ' => 'W', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z', 'Ž' => 'Z',
    'Ż' => 'Z', 'Þ' => 'T', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
    'ä' => 'ae', '&auml;' => 'ae', 'å' => 'a', 'ā' => 'a', 'ą' => 'a', 'ă' => 'a',
    'æ' => 'ae', 'ç' => 'c', 'ć' => 'c', 'č' => 'c', 'ĉ' => 'c', 'ċ' => 'c',
    'ď' => 'd', 'đ' => 'd', 'ð' => 'd', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e', 'ê' => 'e',
    'ë' => 'e', 'ē' => 'e', 'ę' => 'e', 'ě' => 'e', 'ĕ' => 'e', 'ė' => 'e',
    'ƒ' => 'f', 'ĝ' => 'g', 'ğ' => 'g', 'ġ' => 'g', 'ģ' => 'g', 'ĥ' => 'h',
    'ħ' => 'h', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i', 'ī' => 'i',
    'ĩ' => 'i', 'ĭ' => 'i', 'į' => 'i', 'ı' => 'i', 'ĳ' => 'ij', 'ĵ' => 'j',
    'ķ' => 'k', 'ĸ' => 'k', 'ł' => 'l', 'ľ' => 'l', 'ĺ' => 'l', 'ļ' => 'l',
    'ŀ' => 'l', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ń' => 'n', 'ň' => 'n', 'ņ' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n',
    'ŋ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o', 'ö' => 'oe',
    '&ouml;' => 'oe', 'ø' => 'o', 'ō' => 'o', 'ő' => 'o', 'ŏ' => 'o', 'œ' => 'oe',
    'ŕ' => 'r', 'ř' => 'r', 'ŗ' => 'r', 'š' => 's', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u',
    'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ū' => 'u', '&uuml;' => 'ue', 'ů' => 'u', 'ű' => 'u',
    'ŭ' => 'u', 'ũ' => 'u', 'ų' => 'u', 'ŵ' => 'w', 'ý' => 'y', 'ÿ' => 'y',
    'ŷ' => 'y', 'ž' => 'z', 'ż' => 'z', 'ź' => 'z', 'þ' => 't', 'ß' => 'ss',
    'ſ' => 'ss', 'ый' => 'iy', 'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G',
    'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I',
    'Й' => 'Y', 'К' => 'K', 'Л' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'О' => 'O',
    'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T', 'У' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F',
    'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'C', 'Ч' => 'CH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SCH', 'Ъ' => '',
    'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA', 'а' => 'a',
    'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo',
    'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'y', 'к' => 'k', 'л' => 'l',
    'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's',
    'т' => 't', 'у' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'c', 'ч' => 'ch',
    'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'sch', 'ъ' => '', 'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e',
    'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
];

echo str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $string);
```

Comment: fastest way when you have alot lines, for example

Answer (score 24):

As of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
$translatedString = transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove', $string);
```

Answer (score 9):

The string $chain is in the same character encoding as the characters in the array - it's possible, even likely, that the $first_name string is in a different encoding, and so those characters don't match. You might want to try using the multibyte string functions instead.

Try mb_convert_encoding. You might also want to try using HTML_ENTITIES as the to_encoding parameter, then you don't need to worry about how the characters will get converted - it will be very predictable.

Assuming your input to this script is in UTF-8, probably not a bad place to start...

```
$first_name = mb_convert_encoding($first_name, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not.

echo $first_name; // print áááááábéééééébšššš
$first_name = mb_convert_encoding($first_name, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"); 
echo $first_name;  // print áááááábéééééébšššš

Comment: Thank you for answer, the problem was that I have not added " accept-charset="UTF-8" " in the form.

Answer (score 7):

Wish I found this thread sooner. The function I made (that took me way too long) is below:

```
function CheckLetters($field){
    $letters = [
        0 => "a à á â ä æ ã å ā",
        1 => "c ç ć č",
        2 => "e é è ê ë ę ė ē",
        3 => "i ī į í ì ï î",
        4 => "l ł",
        5 => "n ñ ń",
        6 => "o ō ø œ õ ó ò ö ô",
        7 => "s ß ś š",
        8 => "u ū ú ù ü û",
        9 => "w ŵ",
        10 => "y ŷ ÿ",
        11 => "z ź ž ż",
    ];
    foreach ($letters as &$values){
        $newValue = substr($values, 0, 1);
        $values = substr($values, 2, strlen($values));
        $values = explode(" ", $values);
        foreach ($values as &$oldValue){
            while (strpos($field,$oldValue) !== false){
                $field = preg_replace("/" . $oldValue . '/', $newValue, $field, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Comment: This is a genius piece of code. Especially for searching databases that have inconsistent data. I use it to search a country database that is filled with user provided data. This really helps in not adding incorrectly written usercontent. A big thumbs up from me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Incorrectly entered user content is exactly why this was written :)

Comment: just an sidenote, extra starting braces in beginning of the function should be removed obviously

Comment: Nice piece of code, it does however not work if the first character is "dirty". Try CheckLetters('åäö');

Comment: @sboss thanks for pointing that out. Was caused by `while (strpos($field,$oldValue))` as strpos returns 0 if character found at index 0 of string. Fixed by doing a `Not Identical` comparison.

Comment: This code is excellent and provides a basis to add other "problem characters" as needed going forward. Nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

Simple function. Transform strings like 'Ábç Éfg' to 'abc_efg'

```php
/**
 * @param $str
 * @return mixed
 */
function sanitizeString($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[ç]/ui', 'c', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/_+/', '_', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the case.

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter way:

```
$this->load->helper('text');

$string = convert_accented_characters($string);
```

This function uses a companion config file `application/config/foreign_chars.php` to define the to and from array for transliteration.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html#ascii_to_entities

Comment: 1- The question was asked more than 2 years ago 2- The question has an accepted answer. 3- The OP has not mentioned _CI Framework_ and is using _plain php_ so your answer has nothing to do with the question. please pay more attention to the questions before posting an answer

Comment: This helped me after a day of frustration.. Really a good answer for Codeigniter

Comment: @EhsanT 1. The age of the question is irrelevant.  In fact, this site/resource benefits the most when people contribute to old content rather than waiting at the front door for duplicate questions to be posted. 2. An accepted answer doesn't bar anyone from posting a new answer. People should never be deterred from posting after the green tick is awarded.  Though probably not appropriate for this case, the green tick is transferrable. 3. The OP doesn't need to post a whitelist or blacklist of libraries or frameworks. Future researchers may be using CI -- this answer will help them.

Comment: Fair enough @mickmackusa .

Answer (score 1):

```
function correctedText($txt=''){
  $ss = str_split($txt);
    
  for($i=0; $i<count($ss); $i++){
    $asciiNumber = ord($ss[$i]);// get the ascii dec of a single character
    
    // asciiNumber will be from the DEC column showing at https://www.ascii-code.com
    
    // capital letters only checked 
    if($asciiNumber >= 192 && $asciiNumber <= 197)$ss[$i] = 'A';
    elseif($asciiNumber == 198)$ss[$i] = 'AE';
    elseif($asciiNumber == 199)$ss[$i] = 'C';
    elseif($asciiNumber >= 200 && $asciiNumber <= 203)$ss[$i] = 'E';
    elseif($asciiNumber >= 204 && $asciiNumber <= 207)$ss[$i] = 'I';
    elseif($asciiNumber == 209)$ss[$i] = 'N';
    elseif($asciiNumber >= 210 && $asciiNumber <= 214)$ss[$i] = 'O';
    elseif($asciiNumber == 216)$ss[$i] = 'O';
    elseif($asciiNumber >= 217 && $asciiNumber <= 220)$ss[$i] = 'U';
    elseif($asciiNumber == 221)$ss[$i] = 'Y';
  }
    
  $txt = implode('', $ss);
    
  return $txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No one notice that the searching array is with commas inside???

```
$pattern = array("'é'", "'è'", "'ë'", "'ê'", "'É'", "'È'", "'Ë'", "'Ê'", "'á'", "'à'", "'ä'", "'â'", "'å'", "'Á'", "'À'", "'Ä'", "'Â'", "'Å'", "'ó'", "'ò'", "'ö'", "'ô'", "'Ó'", "'Ò'", "'Ö'", "'Ô'", "'í'", "'ì'", "'ï'", "'î'", "'Í'", "'Ì'", "'Ï'", "'Î'", "'ú'", "'ù'", "'ü'", "'û'", "'Ú'", "'Ù'", "'Ü'", "'Û'", "'ý'", "'ÿ'", "'Ý'", "'ø'", "'Ø'", "'œ'", "'Œ'", "'Æ'", "'ç'", "'Ç'");
```

A simple replace with this one will 100% work! :)

```
$pattern = array("é", "è", "ë", "ê", "É", "È", "Ë", "Ê", "á", "à", "ä", "â", "å", "Á", "À", "Ä", "Â", "Å", "ó", "ò", "ö", "ô", "Ó", "Ò", "Ö", "Ô", "í", "ì", "ï", "î", "Í", "Ì", "Ï", "Î", "ú", "ù", "ü", "û", "Ú", "Ù", "Ü", "Û", "ý", "ÿ", "Ý", "ø", "Ø", "œ", "Œ", "Æ", "ç", "Ç");
```

str_replace is working perfectly! Just be more careful in future! It's a junior mistake.

Comment: The "commas' are single quotes or apostrophes.  They are being used as pattern delimiters for the single character regular expression (a poor choice of delimiter in my opinion).  `str_replace()` was in an earlier answer on this page 10 years ago.