# PHP - UTF8 to basic encoding alteration

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, php-5.5

So I'm trying to convert latin characters such as á, é, etc. into their non-latin transliterations (a, e, etc.) I know there is the following:
[PHP replacing special characters like à->a, è->e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152894/php-replacing-special-characters-like-%C3%A0-a-%C3%A8-e)

But none of them seem to have helped... Here is what I have and the results they produce.

```
echo $this->data['last_name'];
$last_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $this->data['last_name']);
echo $last_name;
$last_name = mb_convert_encoding($this->data['last_name'], 'ISO-8859-1');
echo $last_name;
$last_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $this->data['last_name']);
echo $last_name;

-----

Dérmenjian
D�rmenjian
D�rmenjian
D?rmenjian
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and potentially how to fix it? I could always just do a massive array, but I'd prefer a programmatic approach to this problem...

(Not sure it makes a difference, but we're using php 5.5)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was that the locale wasn't being set properly. According to:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#74101
The default was C on my server, so by doing the following I got it to work:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF8');
```

I had previously tried 'en_US' and that was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you just use:

```
str_replace(array("á", "é"), array("a", "e"), $subject);
```

Comment: I think you had missed the part where I said programmatically. I can easily do one massive array, but then I'd have to sit there and take every single non-ascii character and make some massive array. Not only is that going to be a headache (how do I know I didn't miss one?) but also since it's a human doing it, extremely prone to error (what if I do it slightly wrong?). Hence why I asked programmatically. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "UTF8::str_transliterate" -> you can install it via composer -> https://packagist.org/packages/voku/portable-utf8

e.g.: UTF8::str_transliterate('déjà σσς iıii') // deja sss iiii

... or you can use -> https://packagist.org/packages/voku/urlify also available via composer, here you can prefer one language.

e.g.: URLify::filter('Cağaloğlu, çalıştığı, müjde, lazım, mahkûm', 60, 'tr'); // "Cagaloglu-calistigi-mujde-lazim-mahkum"

Mfg Lars :)