# PHP replace symbols all possible variants

Tags: php, replace, combinations

I have array symbols what I want replace, but I need generate all possibillity

```
$lt = array(
    'a' => 'ą',
    'e' => 'ę',
    'i' => 'į',
);
```

For example if I have this string:

```
tazeki
```

There can be huge amount of results:

```
tązeki
tazęki
tązęki
tazekį
tązekį
tazękį
tązękį
```

My question is what formula use to have all variants ?

Comment: @alfallouji noo I not need remove, I need generate all possible strings

Comment: Do you want to replace the varying characters to their ascii equivalent; so $lt value becomes the key?

Comment: @chris85 yes absolutely true

Comment: For clarification: Are you looking for something that gives you all combinations of words based on replacements from the array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152894/php-replacing-special-characters-like-%C3%A0-a-%C3%A8-e

You probably want something like:

`echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you, easy and simple:

What does this code do?

1. Data part

In the data part I just define the string and the replacement's for the single character with a associative  array (search character as key, replacement as value).

2. `getReplacements()` function

This function get's all combinations of the characters which have to be replaced in this format:

```
key   = index in the string
value = character
```

So in this code example the array would look something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [1] => a
    )    
    [1] => Array (
        [3] => e
    )   
    [2] => Array (
        [3] => e
        [1] => a
    )    
    [3] => Array (
        [5] => i
    )    
    [4] => Array (
        [5] => i
        [1] => a
    )    
    [5] => Array (
        [5] => i
        [3] => e
    )    
    [6] => Array (
        [5] => i
        [3] => e
        [1] => a
    )

)
```

As you can see this array holds all combinations of the characters which have to be replaced, in this format:

```
[0] => Array (
     //^^^^^ The entire sub array is the combination which holds the single characters which will be replaced
    [1] => a
   //^     ^ A single character of the full combination which will be replaced
   //| The index of the character in the string (This is that it also works if you have a character multiple times in your string)
   // e.g. 1 ->  t *a* z e k i
   //            ^  ^  ^ ^ ^ ^
   //            |  |  | | | |
   //            0 *1* 2 3 4 5
)
```

So how does it gets all combinations?

Pretty simple I loop through every single character which I want to replace with a foreach loop and then I go through every single combination which I already have and combine it with the character which is currently the value of the foreach loop.

But to get this to work you have to start with a empty array. So as a simple example to see and understand what I mean:

```
Characters which have to be replaced (Empty array is '[]'): [1, 2, 3]
```

```
                               //new combinations for the next iteration
                               |
Character loop for NAN*:

    Combinations:
                  - []         |  -> []

Character loop for 1:

    Combinations:
                  - []    + 1  |  -> [1]    

Character loop for 2:

    Combinations:
                  - []    + 2  |  -> [2]
                  - [1]   + 2  |  -> [1,2]    

Character loop for 3:

    Combinations:
                  - []    + 3  |  -> [3]
                  - [1]   + 3  |  -> [1,3]
                  - [2]   + 3  |  -> [2,3]         
                  - [1,2] + 3  |  -> [1,2,3]    
                               //^ All combinations here
```

<sub>* NAN: not a number</sub>

So as you can see there is always: `(2^n)-1` combinations in total. Also from this method there is a empty array left in the combination array, so before I return the array I just use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove all empty arrays and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the entire array.

3. Replacement part

So to get all characters from the string where will build the combinations out of I use this line:

```
array_intersect(str_split($str), array_keys($replace))
```

This just get's all coincidences with [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) from the string as array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and the keys from the replace array with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

In this code the array which you pass to the `getReplacements()` function would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
   //^     ^ The single character which is in the string and also in the replace array
   //| Index in the string from the character
    [3] => e
    [5] => i
)
```

4. Replace all combinations

At the end you only have to replace all combinations in the source string with the replace array. For this I loop just through every combination and replace every single character in the string from the combination with the matching character from the replace array.

This can be simply done with this line:

```
$tmp = substr_replace($tmp, $replace[$v], $k, 1);
     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^  ^ Length of the replacement
     //|                    |             | Index from the string, where it should replace
     //|                    | Get the replaced character to replace it
     //| Replaces every single character one by one in the string
```

For more information about `substr_replace()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

After this line you just add the replaced string in the result array and rest the string to the source string again.

Code:

```
<?php

    //data
    $str = "tazeki"; 

    $replace = array(
        'a' => 'ą',
        'e' => 'ę',
        'i' => 'į',
    );


    function getReplacements($array) {

        //initalize array
        $results = [[]];

        //get all combinations
        foreach ($array as $k => $element) {
            foreach ($results as $combination)
                $results[] = [$k => $element] + $combination;
        }

        //return filtered array
        return array_values(array_filter($results));

    }

    //get all combinations to replace
    $combinations = getReplacements(array_intersect(str_split($str), array_keys($replace)));

    //replace all combinations
    foreach($combinations as $word) {
        $tmp = $str;
        foreach($word as $k => $v)
            $tmp = substr_replace($tmp, $replace[$v], $k, 1);
        $result[] = $tmp;
    }

    //print data
    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tązeki
    [1] => tazęki
    [2] => tązęki
    [3] => tazekį
    [4] => tązekį
    [5] => tazękį
    [6] => tązękį
)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I made test today on PHP 7 and it returned empty array.

Comment: I copied Your code as it is and get empty array as a result. Solution of Yuriy Novikov worked for me.

Comment: Hmm funny thing. When I changed name of the function to get_replacements it worked... And before I was wrong. Not empty array, but empty page like error BUT I have error reporting on. Never mind anyway.

Comment: Thank's, Nice, Best and lovely answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution particularly for your task. You can pass any word and any array for replacements, it should work.

```
<?php

function getCombinations($word, $charsReplace)
{
    $charsToSplit = array_keys($charsReplace);

    $pattern = '/('.implode('|', $charsToSplit).')/';

    // split whole word into parts by replacing symbols
    $parts = preg_split($pattern, $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $replaceParts = array();
    $placeholder = '';

    // create string with placeholders (%s) for sptrinf and array of replacing symbols
    foreach ($parts as $wordPart) {
        if (isset($charsReplace[$wordPart])) {
            $replaceParts[] = $wordPart;
            $placeholder .= '%s';
        } else {
            $placeholder .= $wordPart;
        }
    }

    $paramsCnt = count($replaceParts);
    $combinations = array();
    $combinationsCnt = pow(2, $paramsCnt);

    // iterate all combinations (with help of binary codes)
    for ($i = 0; $i < $combinationsCnt; $i++) {
        $mask = sprintf('%0'.$paramsCnt.'b', $i);
        $sprintfParams = array($placeholder);
        foreach ($replaceParts as $index => $char) {
            $sprintfParams[] = $mask[$index] == 1 ? $charsReplace[$char] : $char;
        }
        // fill current combination into placeholder and collect it in array
        $combinations[] = call_user_func_array('sprintf', $sprintfParams);
    }

    return $combinations;
}


$lt = array(
    'a' => 'ą',
    'e' => 'ę',
    'i' => 'į',
);
$word = 'stazeki';

$combinations = getCombinations($word, $lt);

print_r($combinations);

// Оutput:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => stazeki
//     [1] => stazekį
//     [2] => stazęki
//     [3] => stazękį
//     [4] => stązeki
//     [5] => stązekį
//     [6] => stązęki
//     [7] => stązękį
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation in PHP :

```
<?php
/**
 * String variant generator
 */
class stringVariantGenerator
{
    /**
     * Contains assoc of char => array of all its variations
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_mapping = array();

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * 
     * @param array $mapping Assoc array of char => array of all its variation
     */
    public function __construct(array $mapping = array())
    {
        $this->_mapping = $mapping;
    }

    /**
     * Generate all variations
     * 
     * @param string $string String to generate variations from 
     * 
     * @return array Assoc containing variations
     */
    public function generate($string) 
    {
        return array_unique($this->parseString($string));
    }

    /**
     * Parse a string and returns variations
     * 
     * @param string $string String to parse
     * @param int $position Current position analyzed in the string
     * @param array $result Assoc containing all variations
     * 
     * @return array Assoc containing variations
     */
    protected function parseString($string, $position = 0, array &$result = array()) 
    {
        if ($position <= strlen($string) - 1)
        {
            if (isset($this->_mapping[$string{$position}]))
            {
                foreach ($this->_mapping[$string{$position}] as $translatedChar)
                {
                    $string{$position} = $translatedChar;
                    $this->parseString($string, $position + 1, $result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->parseString($string, $position + 1, $result);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $result[] = $string;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

// This is where you define what are the possible variations for each char
$mapping = array(
    'e' => array('#', '_'),
    'p' => array('*'),
);

$word = 'Apple love!';
$generator = new stringVariantGenerator($mapping);
print_r($generator->generate($word));
```

It would return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => A**l# lov#!
    [1] => A**l# lov_!
    [2] => A**l_ lov#!
    [3] => A**l_ lov_!
)
```

In your case, if you want to use the letter itself as a valid translated value, just add it into the array.

```
$lt = array(
    'a' => array('a', 'ą'),
    'e' => array('e', 'ę'),
    'i' => array('i', 'į'),
);
```

Comment: The other answers are also implementations in php ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with keys and value but as two arrays definatley.

```
$find = array('ą','ę','į');
$replace = array('a', 'e', 'i');
$string = 'tązekį';
echo str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question - he's looking for all possible permutations.

Comment: Comment 2 and comment 3 i thought were pretty specific; maybe not cause haven't seen any action on this since...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand your question, but here is my answer :-)

```
$word = 'taxeki';
$word_arr = array();
$word_arr[] = $word;

//Loop through the $lt-array where $key represents what char to search for
//$letter what to replace with
//
foreach($lt as $key=>$letter) {

    //Loop through each char in the $word-string
    for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen($word)-1; $i++ ) {
        $char = substr( $word, $i, 1 ); 

        //If current letter in word is same as $key from $lt-array
        //then add a word the $word_arr where letter is replace with
        //$letter from the $lt-array
        if ($char === $key) {
            $word_arr[] = str_replace($char, $letter, $word);
        }

    } 

}

var_dump($word_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a known number of elements in your array, and I am assuming that that number is 3. You will have to have additional loops if you have additional elements in your $lt array.

```
$lt = array(
   'a' => array('a', 'x'),
   'e' => array('e', 'x'),
   'i' => array('i', 'x')
);
$str = 'tazeki';
foreach ($lt['a'] as $a)
    foreach ($lt['e'] as $b)
        foreach ($lt['i'] as $c) {
            $newstr = str_replace(array_keys($lt), array($a, $b, $c), $str);
            echo "$newstr<br />\n";
        }
```

If the number of elements in `$lt` is unknown or variable then this is not a good solution.

Comment: I had trouble copy/pasting the accented characters, so I just used 'x' - you will need to replace those x's with the appropriate accented characters.

Comment: There is no $lt['b'] ?

Comment: Sorry - typo. fixed now.

Comment: Seems not very flexible, What would you do if there are 5 characters to replace ? 5 loops?

Comment: Not too flexible, but for the problem as stated I think it's the simplest and most straightforward answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well, though @Rizier123 and others have already provided good answers will clear explanations, I would like to leave my contribution as well. This time, honoring the Way of the Short Source Code over readability ... ;-)

```
$lt   = array('a' => 'ą', 'e' => 'ę', 'i' => 'į');
$word = 'tazeki';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
    $lt[$word[$i]] && $r[pow(2, $u++)] = [$lt[$word[$i]], $i];

for ($i = 1; $i < pow(2, count($r)); $i++) {
    for ($w = $word, $u = end(array_keys($r)); $u > 0; $u >>= 1)
        ($i & $u) && $w = substr_replace($w, $r[$u][0], $r[$u][1], 1);
    $res[] = $w;
}

print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tązeki
    [1] => tazęki
    [2] => tązęki
    [3] => tazekį
    [4] => tązekį
    [5] => tazękį
    [6] => tązękį
)
```

Comment: I think you didn't had error reporting on: `Undefined variable t,u,z,k` and a lot of `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: Yeah @Rizier123, I would not recommend anyone to use it in production even though the result comes out right. Coming from a Perl background I just couldn't resist some code golfing :-P