# Charachter encoding conversion from different encoding to English one

Tags: php

I am trying to convert all the chars from all other languages to English Language, but failing to do so. My function doesn't replace them correctly for some reason. Seams that it is replacing only some of the charachters. Could be `str_replace` not working for this? Tried also other methods with `iconv` and `mb_convert_string` and not working.

Live Example
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a43f3cd959b3885281481145ce3c720fefec6d7

```
<?php
function decode_utf8($string){
    $accented = array(
        'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ă', 'Ą',
        'Ç', 'Ć', 'Č', 'Œ',
        'Ď', 'Đ',
        'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ă', 'ą',
        'ç', 'ć', 'č', 'œ',
        'ď', 'đ',
        'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ę', 'Ě',
        'Ğ',
        'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'İ',
        'Ĺ', 'Ľ', 'Ł',
        'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ę', 'ě',
        'ğ',
        'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ı',
        'ĺ', 'ľ', 'ł',
        'Ñ', 'Ń', 'Ň',
        'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', 'Ø', 'Ő',
        'Ŕ', 'Ř',
        'Ś', 'Ş', 'Š',
        'ñ', 'ń', 'ň',
        'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'ö', 'ø', 'ő',
        'ŕ', 'ř',
        'ś', 'ş', 'š',
        'Ţ', 'Ť',
        'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ų', 'Ü', 'Ů', 'Ű',
        'Ý', 'ß',
        'Ź', 'Ż', 'Ž',
        'ţ', 'ť',
        'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ų', 'ü', 'ů', 'ű',
        'ý', 'ÿ',
        'ź', 'ż', 'ž',
        'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р',
        'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'р',
        'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я',
        'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я'
        );

    $replace = array(
        'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AE', 'A', 'A',
        'C', 'C', 'C', 'CE',
        'D', 'D',
        'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'ae', 'a', 'a',
        'c', 'c', 'c', 'ce',
        'd', 'd',
        'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E',
        'G',
        'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I',
        'L', 'L', 'L',
        'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e',
        'g',
        'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i',
        'l', 'l', 'l',
        'N', 'N', 'N',
        'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O',
        'R', 'R',
        'S', 'S', 'S',
        'n', 'n', 'n',
        'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o',
        'r', 'r',
        's', 's', 's',
        'T', 'T',
        'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U',
        'Y', 'Y',
        'Z', 'Z', 'Z',
        't', 't',
        'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u',
        'y', 'y',
        'z', 'z', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'B', 'r', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'X', '3', 'N', 'N', 'K', 'N', 'M', 'H', 'O', 'N', 'P',
        'a', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'x', '3', 'n', 'n', 'k', 'n', 'm', 'h', 'o', 'p',
        'C', 'T', 'Y', 'O', 'X', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'W', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'E', 'O', 'R',
        'c', 't', 'y', 'o', 'x', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'o', 'r'
    );
    $arr = array_combine($accented, $replace);
    foreach($arr as $accent=>$replace) {
        $string = str_replace($accented, $replace, $string);
    }
    //return $string;
    return str_replace($accented, $replace, $string);
}
$string = 'Șșăîț';
$string = decode_utf8($string);
var_Dump($string);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152894/php-replacing-special-characters-like-%C3%A0-a-%C3%A8-e Did you try this?

Comment: [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) is better suited for this kinda thing.

Comment: Tried all from there and this one was almost the best working and the best one was `slugify` function. Tried also with strtr and did not work again. Thank you.