# Generate link_rewrite variable in PrestaShop

Tags: php, api, soap, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm writing a product importer for PrestaShop. This importer should connect to server using SOAP API.

Generally everything works fine, but I need to generate a string for `link_rewrite` column in `ps_product_lang` table to insert it correctly. The problem is that imported string, which I want to use for generating `linkRewrite` parameter contains Polish sings like ó,ł,ż etc.

I found a method called `updateLinkRewrite()` which generates SEO friendly URL and replace Polish chars on English chars in admin page but this is a JS method.

Does a similar method to `updateLinkRewrite()` exist in PrestaShop admin controllers in PHP-part?

Comment: Have a look at this post, maybe it will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152894/php-replacing-special-characters-like-%C3%A0-a-%C3%A8-e

Comment: thanks a lot, very helpfully :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a simple solution in PHP inside Prestashop :

```
Tools::str2url($string);
```

Works since 1.5 and still in 1.7.